# "the annotation @Autowired is disallowed for this location" error on Eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to use `@Autowired` for a file storage service, but apparently I'm doing it wrong.

I'm currently trying to create a file upload service using Spring Boot on Eclipse.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public String onUpload(@RequestParam("file")  MultipartFile file, CVtestForm cvForm, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {

    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;


    return "upload_show";   
}
```

I'm expecting `storageService` be wired to `FileStorageService`, which implements it.

Comment: Can you post your `StorageService ` class ?

Answer (score 8):

[@Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) can't be used for local variable, you should add it outside method scope, as field for example:

```
@Autowired
StorageService storageService;

@PostMapping("/upload")
public String onUpload(@RequestParam("file")  MultipartFile file, CVtestForm cvForm, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
```

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

Comment: My bad, tried to use this annotation inside a method. But after declaring it at class level the error is gone.